# Laravel belong to not working with app\user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PasswordSecurity extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {   
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

error is

> "Trying to get property 'passwordSecurity' of non-object"

```
if(count($user->passwordSecurity)){
```

this is the code for controller file where I got error.

Comment: Could you post how you are trying to access the model? The exception probably doesn't come from the code above.

Comment: please post the code that calls `$user->passwordSecurity()` and *User* class too

Comment: if(count($user->passwordSecurity)){ this is the code for controller file where I got error.

Comment: can you write the  codethat got  this error? ` error "Trying to get property 'passwordSecurity' of non-object" `

Comment: @SamanAhmadi this is the code "if(count($user->passwordSecurity))"

Comment: Check if the $user is empty or not.

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei $user not empty

Comment: Have you set relationship in your user model?

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei yes

Comment: The error is saying you're trying to access a property (`passwordSecurity `) on something that isn't an object this would leave me to believe that `$user` is not set. Please can you edit your question an provide the **whole** controller method (or at least show how you're setting the `$user` variable).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have only defined the relationship on the `PasswordSecurity` model which means you can only access it from an instance of that model, for example, `$passwordSecurity->user`. You need to define the relationship on the `User` model as well to be able to access it from a instance of the `User` model, for example:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function passwordSecurity()
    {   
        return $this->hasOne('App\PasswordSecurity');
    }
}
```

In the example above you `User` model is assumed to have a `password_security_id` foreign key. If the foreign key in your `User` model has a different name, you can pass a second parameter to the `hasOne` method to specify its name, for example `hasOne('App\PasswordSecurity', 'foreign_key');`

Answer (score 0):

It says $user is null , it's not for your relation.
just check why $user is null